# How to process the below xml that I have using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
<Row ss:Index="14">
<Cell ss:StyleID="TableRowHeader" ss:Index="2">
<Data ss:Type="String">10000</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="TableRowHeader" ss:Index="3">
<Data ss:Type="String">S00001</Data>    
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="TableRowHeader" ss:Index="6">
<Data ss:Type="String">SPI-37-2018</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="TableRowHeader" ss:Index="7">
<Data ss:Type="String">02/26/2018</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="TableRowHeader" ss:Index="8">
<Data ss:Type="String">22</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="TableRowHeader" ss:Index="9">
<Data ss:Type="String">02/26/2018</Data>
```

I want to extract data from the specific ss:StyleId and ss:Index.
Can you please suggest a way
I tried print(xmlTree.find('.//Cell').attrib['ss:StyleID']), but it shows NoneType has no attrib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: XML has namespaces. Please post at least root or parent tag that defines namespace prefix like *ss*.

Comment: I have added the parent tag here. Thanks :)

Comment: Still not helpful as we do not know what *ss* is defined. I meant at least the node that defines namespace prefix. That can be parent but usually is root tag. Find `xmlns:ss`.